# How can i count the frequency of those of a number showing from a countif but only once?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, excel-2010, countif

Hi I have a bunch of data and I need to know how much of each value show up and how often the frequency is only corresponding to the unique value. I used a countif to count the unique value but I wanna know the frequency of the amount of times it shows up.

Sorry if this doesnt make any sense here's a screenshot to maybe help you understand better.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufnq3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change the formula in B1 to,

   ```
   =IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1, A1)=1, COUNTIF(A:A, A1), TEXT(,))
   ```

   and fill down to match the values in column A.
2. Copy column B into column E then Sort and Remove Duplicates¹.
3. This simplifies the formula in F1 to,

   ```
   =COUNTIF(B:B, E1)
   ```

Fill down to match the values in column E.

[image]

---

¹ <sub>The Custom Number Format for column E is `F\r\eq 0_)`.</sub>